# paste token using useReducer with useContext and get undefined part 2

Tags: next.js, use-context, use-reducer

yeah i know this is my part 2 problem. You can see the part 1 in [paste token in useReducer with useContext in nextjs and get undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739306/paste-token-in-usereducer-with-usecontext-in-nextjs-and-get-undefined). So in the part 1 my problem was solved and i didn't get undefined anymore but instead i get an empty object on console.log(stateAuth.auth). Please help me! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two errors in your `DataProvider` component.

```
const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem("firstLogin");
if (firstLogin === true) {
  async (token) => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users/", {
...
```

Everything gets serialized to a `string` for `localStorage`, so `firstLogin` will be a `string` and can never `=== true` as `===` is a strict equality check.

Where is `firstLogin` set?  Doesn't it make sense to fetch a token if some property *doesn't* exist in `localStorage`, since new users wouldn't have any data?

---

Inside of that code block you write an `async` function that takes a `token` and does some stuff.  You don't *call* this function and you don't save it to a variable either.  You just...write it.  I get an eslint error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." on this whole section.

Where is this `token` variable supposed to come from?

Comment: Thank you soo much bro, i was confused for like 1 month.